# select from table with between

Tags: sql, oracle

please, help advice.

I have a table.

```
id|score_max|score_min| segment
--|---------|---------|--------
1 |264      |         |girl
2 |263      | 250     |girl+
3 |249      | 240     |girl
4 |         | 239     |girl
```

It is not necessary to obtain a value depending on the value of the score.
But it can be null.

For example, 260 is value from other table

```
select segment
from mytable
where score_max<260 and score_min>260
```

Output:

```
2 |263      | 250     |girl+
```

but if value =200, sql is not correct

How to make a request correctly?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I need to get a segment that depends on the score. For example, score =245, then get id =3, if score = 200 - id=4

Comment: Show your desired output and explain the requirement clearly.

Comment: @vasilek *if score = 200 - id=4* why? 200 is less than score_min = 239.

Comment: @forpas last interval is 239 and less, so if score=200 then i have to get id=4 and segment=girl

Comment: For the last interval to be 239 or less, `score_max` should be 239, not `score_min`

Comment: Likewise `id = 1` should have `score_min = 264`, not `score_max`

Comment: @vasilek check your sample data and make changes.

Answer (score 2):

For this sample data that makes more sense:

```
id|score_max|score_min| segment
--|---------|---------|--------
1 |         | 264     |girl
2 |263      | 250     |girl+
3 |249      | 240     |girl
4 |239      |         |girl
```

you can get the result that you want like this:

```
select * 
from tablename
where 
  (? >= score_min or score_min is null)
  and 
  (? <= score_max or score_max is null)
```

Replace `?` with the value that you search for.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2ea3af006ad2ab40e6af764e2e5bc6ea).

Comment: Was just revisiting to see if the question had been updated and possibly giving this exact answer...

Comment: Although actually I was going to use `COALESCE(score_min, 0)` etc.

Comment: COALESCE could be used with 0 and 2^31-1 for max but I don't know if the values can be negative or what would be the greatest value.

Comment: Indeed, that would be making some assumptions - had there been some sample `table2` data it would have made life easier. Of course I don't really know why there are `NULL` values in `score_min` and `score_max` to begin with, it doesn't make a lot of sense to me...